# Bash - How to remove all white spaces from a given text file?

Tags: linux, bash, sed

I want to remove all the white spaces from a given text file.

Is there any shell command available for this ?

Or, how to use `sed` for this purpose?

I want something like below:

> $ cat hello.txt | sed ....

I tried this : `cat hello.txt | sed 's/ //g'` .

But it removes only spaces, not tabs.

Thanks.

Comment: by "all whitespace", do you mean newlines as well?

Answer (score 192, accepted):

```
$ man tr
NAME
    tr - translate or delete characters

SYNOPSIS
    tr [OPTION]... SET1 [SET2]

DESCRIPTION
   Translate, squeeze, and/or delete characters from standard 
   input, writing to standard output.
```

In order to wipe all whitespace including newlines you can try:

```
cat file.txt | tr -d " \t\n\r"
```

You can also use the character classes defined by tr (credits to [htompkins](https://stackoverflow.com/users/315868/htompkins) comment):

```
cat file.txt | tr -d "[:space:]"
```

For example, in order to wipe just horizontal white space:

```
cat file.txt | tr -d "[:blank:]"
```

Comment: You can also use the character classes defined by `tr`. Examples:

To delete _all_ whitespace:
`cat file.txt | tr -d "[:space:]"`

To delete all horizontal whitespace:
`cat file.txt | tr -d "[:blank:]"`

Comment: @user3901666 it will remove whitespace, yes, if the output produced will match what you want is hard to say - what have you tried?

Answer (score 32):

Much simpler to my opinion:

```
sed -r 's/\s+//g' filename
```

Comment: I've just tried this and it outputs the amended text to STDOUT but doesn't change the file itself.

Comment: @MaxWilliams - just use the -i (dash i) flag with sed

Comment: This does not remove newlines, not sure if that was wanted by OP.

Comment: This also removes every instance of the letter S on macOS bash! :)

Answer (score 18):

I think you may use sed to wipe out the space while not losing some infomation like changing to another line.

```
cat hello.txt | sed '/^$/d;s/[[:blank:]]//g'
```

To apply into existing file, use following:

```
sed -i '/^$/d;s/[[:blank:]]//g' hello.txt
```

Comment: Fine, but I don't think I'll be able to bring myself to write `tr -d " " < infile.txt > outfile.txt`

Comment: Hello, this works thanks, but I would appreciate some explaination.

Answer (score 11):

Try this:

```
sed -e 's/[\t ]//g;/^$/d'
```

(found [here](http://bash.cyberciti.biz/file-management/sed-remove-all-blank-spaces-from-textfile/))

The first part removes all tabs (`\t`) and spaces, and the second part removes all empty lines

Comment: This actually works. Care to explain sed -e 's/[\t ]//g;/^$/d' particularly /^$/d'. I know ^ is for start of string, $ is for end. /d is for delete when using sed. But how does this interpretation lead of deletion of white spaces?

Comment: I added an explanation. `^$` matches an empty line since it's looking for "start of line" (^) and then immediately after, "end of line" ($).

Comment: Removes all instances of letter S on macOS bash.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to remove **ALL** whitespace, even newlines:

```
perl -pe 's/\s+//g' file
```

Answer (score 5):

This answer is similar to other however as some people have been complaining that the output goes to STDOUT i am just going to suggest redirecting it to the original file and overwriting it. I would never normally suggest this but sometimes quick and dirty works.

```
cat file.txt | tr -d " \t\n\r" > file.txt
```

Answer (score 4):

Easiest way for me:

```
echo "Hello my name is Donald" | sed  s/\ //g
```

Answer (score 2):

This is probably the simplest way of doing it:

```
sed -r 's/\s+//g' filename > output
mv ouput filename
```

Answer (score 2):

Dude, Just python test.py in your terminal.

```
f = open('/home/hduser/Desktop/data.csv' , 'r')

x = f.read().split()
f.close()

y = ' '.join(x)
f = open('/home/hduser/Desktop/data.csv','w')
f.write(y)
f.close()
```

Comment: Sorry to bump an old thread, but isn't `f.read().strip("\t\n\r ")` more efficient?

Comment: What if there are two or more subsequent spaces,tabs etc. b/w words? I think your solution is for leading and trailing white-spaces. If you want one liner, you can easily convert the above code.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
tr -d " \t" <filename
```

See the manpage for tr(1) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

hmm...seems like something on the order of `sed -e "s/[ \t\n\r\v]//g" < hello.txt` should be in the right ballpark (seems to work under cygwin in any case).