# Are Google Sheets Stored in a GCP Storage Bucket Somewhere?

Tags: google-sheets, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I have a task where I need to download a Google Sheet in .csv format, and upload it to a Google Storage Bucket.

But my question is, if configured properly, could a Google Sheet already be stored in a bucket by default? I figure it needs to be stored somewhere, and if associated with the correct GCP account, perhaps it is.

I've done some googling trying to find info on this topic, but haven't found anything yet. Any information or resources on this would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure with configuring sheets to store in a bucket, but you might have some ideas by doing it via apps script. Kindly see this [reference](https://ramblings.mcpher.com/gcp/cloud-storage-and-apps-script/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can answer partially. Google Storage is based on [Colossus](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/storage-data-transfer/a-peek-behind-colossus-googles-file-system). Workspace app (Docs, Sheet, Slides,...) and drive required also storage and are, logically, also based on Colossus.

In this manner, you can say that both are stored on the same technical layer.

But that's all. Workspace/drive world is a SaaS world, fully managed by Google and thus not in relation with your Google Cloud Project, and thus with your Google Storage bucket. In addition, if it was the case, the data aren't stored in CSV format by Google, but in a proprietary format I guess.

---

For the CSV generation, I found, and tested, this [amazing answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61107170/11372593)