# How to remove all spaces in cygwin

Tags: grep, gawk, gnuwin32

I have multiple .txt files in a folder i want to remove all spaces from every line of every file how do i do so?

So like file1.txt contains

```
 a a a a 
 2 2 2 2
```

and file 2.txt contains

```
3 3 3 3
4 4 4 4
```

I want the outcome to remove spaces so like,

file1.txt after

```
aaaa
2222
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this post out.
[How to remove all white spaces from a given text file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9953448/how-to-remove-all-white-spaces-from-a-given-text-file)

You want the `tr` command. You can do something like `cat file.txt | tr -d " \t\n\r"`

And if you wanna do it for all the files in the directory, you could use a find command. Something like `find . | xargs tr -d " \t\n\r`

EDIT - Just noticed you wanna keep the line breaks. You can omit the newlines from the tr command

Comment: UUOC: `cat file.txt | tr -d " \t\n\r"` -> `tr -d " \t\n\r" < file.txt`. Consider using the POSIX character class `[:blank:]`.

Comment: Good point Ed. It's always better to be explicit, makes things easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

Using sed

```
 $sed -e "s/ //g" file1.txt
aaaa
2222
```

You can add `-i` to change the file in place.