# How to remove all white spaces from stdout input via AWK in linux

Tags: linux, awk

I want to remove all the whitespaces from the ouptut of $date by using $awk but somehow it does not work as intended, what am I missing here?

`date |  awk '{gsub(/ *\| */,",")}1'`

> Sat 28 Mar 23:13:22 CET 2020

Comment: `date |  awk '{gsub(/[[:space:]]+/,",")}1'`? See https://ideone.com/OlrHKP

Comment: $ date | awk '{gsub(/[[:space:]]+/,",")}1'
Sat 28 Mar 23:21:36 CET 2020

Comment: `tr -d '[:space:]'`

Comment: Please add sample input (no descriptions, no images, no links) and your desired output for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Comment: @RagnarLothbrok No, see https://ideone.com/OlrHKP, result is `Sat,28,Mar,2020,10:12:13,PM,UTC`

Comment: Weird, it doesn't work for me. Tried to use fish and zsh instead of bash but it's the same.

Comment: `$ date |  awk '{gsub(/[[:space:]]+/,",")}1'
Sat 28 Mar 23:25:35 CET 2020`

Comment: How about just: `date | awk '{gsub(/ /,",")}1'`

Comment: `date | awk '{gsub(/ /,",")}1'` Works, tr also works as workaround, thanks. Take care.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove all white spaces from a given text file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9953448/how-to-remove-all-white-spaces-from-a-given-text-file)

Comment: Seem, like you've been mostly nudged in the needed direction. Note: `awk` (not sure if all implementations) defaults to extended regex, hence use `|` and not `\|` for or. Note2: `*` means any number of occurrences incl. none, you probably wanted to say `+` meaning one ore more.

Comment: @OndrejK. all awk implementations use EREs and it's not just a default - they ONLY use EREs.

Comment: @Ragnar - do you REALLY want to convert the date to `Sat28Mar23:13:22CET2020`? If so, why?

Answer (score 1):

for this `sed` might be easier

```
$ date | sed 's/ //g'

SatMar2819:00:12EDT2020
```

Answer (score -1):

Solution with the underscore set as the separator:

```
date | awk '{gsub(/ /,"_")}1'
```

Workaround without awk(no separator):

```
date | tr -d '[:space:]'
```

Comment: That awk "solution" doesn't make sense. If you don't want an underscore then don't type an underscore.